# How to setup Android Library module and be referenced by multiple projects in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

My company is making several Android projects on Android Studio, which all of them share some similar codes, such as custom views, customised HTTP clients, and many other things.

The problem I am facing is, I am new to Android Studio and I am not sure how to extract these common codes across several projects to a single Android Library modules that will be referenced by these projects.

In Eclipse it is very simple, just create a new Android Library project, and then move your code over there, and set the Android Application projects to reference the common library.

How can such refactoring be done by Android Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Our company used a structure with multiple projects with shared modules. Suppose you have 2 projects, project1 and project2 which are 2 independent Android Studio projects and want to share some modules. The folder structure will be like this:

```
source-code-root-folder/
    + android-studio-project1/
         + project1-app-module/
         + project1-internal-module/
    + android-studio-project2/
         + project2-app-module/
         + project2-internal-module/
    + shared-module1/
    + shared-module2/
```

You can first create the projects and modules from Android studio. Then relocate the folders like the structure above. Then update the setting in project1 by putting this settings in the `source-code-root-folder/android-studio-project1/settings.gradle`:

```
include ':android-studio-project1'
include ':project1-app-module'
include ':project1-internal-module'
include ':..:shared-module1'
include ':..:shared-module2'
```

Then open the `android-studio-project1/project1-app-module/build.gradle` and update the dependencies:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':project1-internal-module')
    compile project(':..:shared-module1')
    compile project(':..:shared-module2')
}
```

This will make project1 be able to load the internal module and the shared modules as well. Try sync and build your project1 by running build.gradle in the project1 and it should work. Of course similar setting can be used for the project2.

Hope that this can help you.

Comment: Out of so many (unfortunately "accepted") answers on SO, this one is the only one that does both **share a custom library among multiple projects** and **keep only one copy of the source** instead of copying it to every project. Thank you Chris. Three tip though, 1) In `settings.gradle` you can put all included modules on a single line separated by commas like so `include ':mod1', ':mod2'`. 2) In `build.gradle`, replace all `compile`s with `implementation`. 3) a module inside another _project_ can be referenced like so `':../ProjectX/:moduleX'`

Comment: i'm getting `Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: The project name '..' must not start or end with a '.'. Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement` this error.
while using `include ':..:opencv-module'` in my settings.gradle