# Android Studio compiles dependencies but doesnt package aar into apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, aar

I am not that old to Gradle system. I have a Android project with an app with a library.
I used [Android Developer Page](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#aar-contents)  and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125937/how-to-setup-android-library-module-and-be-referenced-by-multiple-projects-in-an) for setting up but a bit different configuration which is as follows

```
source-code-root-folder/
   build.gradle
   + app-module/
       build.gradle
   + library-AAR-module/
       build.gradle
```

I have put the library in the dependency in the app module

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library-AAR-module')
}
```

when I assemble, it compiles the library module but Neither I find the classes of library in the app nor the APK of the app contains the aar package stuffs. Am i doing wrong setup?

Comment: Please add the full build.gradle files of your modules

Comment: I have found out the solution to the problem. The problem was I had introduce the flavor in the library and because of that, the dependencies should also be flavor based.  I have got the help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196974/how-to-define-different-dependencies-for-different-product-flavors